# WordPress Loop Error

Tags: wordpress

First let me say that I have been working on this issue for about 2 weeks and I have looked all over the place for an answer. Ive gone to various forums, blogs, the WordPress Codex and just about any and all places I could find. I still cannot get this to work properly. As a last resort I am coming here to see if maybe someone can assist me with it.

My issue is this. I am building a free Wordpress theme, http://wp-awesome.themeawesome.com. I will be submitting it to the WordPress Theme Repository and hopefully get it hosted so people can download it. One of the requirements is that a theme cannot generate any errors. Everything is working perfectly and there are no errors except one. I get the following error message when I go to a second page:

***Notice: Undefined variable: do_not_duplicate in /--/--/--/--/--/--/wp-awesome/index.php on line 68***

As you can see on the front page there is a featured post slider. This slider is will display posts that are tagged "featured". I am using the following code for this specific query:

```
    <?php 
            $mytag = mytheme_option( 'featured_tag' );
            $thecount = mytheme_option( 'featured_count' );
            $my_query = new WP_Query("tag=$mytag&showposts=$thecount");
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
            $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;
        ?>

// post stuff here

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Now obviously on the home page I do not want the posts that are displaying in the slider to display on the front page in the regular loop below it. So i found the following code that seems to work great:

```
    <?php 
if (is_home()) { 
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    query_posts(array(
        'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate,
        'paged' => $paged
    )); }
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

// post stuff

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

the only problem is when you click on another page at the bottom the error shows up:

***Notice: Undefined variable: do_not_duplicate in /--/--/--/--/--/--/wp-awesome/index.php on line 68***

I know the error is appearing because when you go to a second or third page, there is nothing defining the do_not_duplicate param. Any ideas how to fix this?

Any help is greatly appreciated and I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy & quick fix ( not necessary best ) would be to declare the $do_not_duplicate variable in the theme's header.php file located in: wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/header.php. If it's an array, you might need to declare it's elements. Like this:

```
<?php
  //  declaration of $do_not_duplicate array
  for ( $i = 0; $i < 100; $i++ ) {
    $do_not_duplicate[$i] = 0;
  };
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @marcinsdance, appreciated, only problem is I have no clue what you mean...lol - usually this is not a problem as most themes I create are for clients, so general errors like this really do not matter. However, trying to follow WP standards is really hard. Any chance you could provide an example how I would go about implementing your fix so i can see how it works. Again thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Again, thank you very much. I am going to add that and see how it goes. I also think it was something I did as well. I took the slider code out of the index file and put it in a content-featured.php file and called it with the get_template_part. For some reason it doesnt recognize the do_not_duplicate in that fiel. But if I add the slider directly to the index.php file. It works fine for some reason. Oh well...lol but thank you for your time and assistance.